# overridePendingTransition only works for exit animation not enter animation

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my code, I don't know what goes wrong
I'm using built-in animation so there should not be anything wrong
And I'm using Android Studio
I don't know if it is because the simulator is too slow or what
I can see the exit animation but there is no enter animation

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    anotherActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.antoherActivity);
    anotherActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent another = new Intent();
            another.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            another.putExtra("testInput", "test");
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(another);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Is the enter animation missing in this `MainActivity` or is it missing in the `SecondActivity`?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_in, R.anim.top_out);
       }});
```

**/res/anim/top_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
  <translate 
      android:fromYDelta="0" 
      android:toYDelta="-100%p" 
      android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**/res/anim/bottom_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
  <translate 
      android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
      android:toYDelta="0" 
      android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```